# Editing choice-values (drop-down menu) in a live list

Tags: list, choice-field

I have to edit one (out of five) choice-value in a custom created column called "Status". Via list-settings - Change column - Additional column settings I get the list of these five values. Can I safely change one of these values without changing values on all items?

F.e. if I have the choice-values "A", "B", "C" and "D" can I change value "B" to "F" and have all items that have value "B" changed to value "F" while the other items are not impacted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choice fields are stored as normal text, so the answer to your question is twofold. Yes, you can safely change the column definition without affecting the current items in your list; this also implies that no, you cannot have the value currently stored in an item changed accordingly: it will remain as it is (basically, "orphaned").

If you need to change the current value for all items, you have to do it via code or more easily/quicker in DataSheet view mode

Answer (score 0):

Create another option such as "F" for status.
Create a trigger field with a value of "0".
Publish your form.

Create a workflow that looks for the value of "1" for the trigger.

- If trigger = 1
  - If status = B
    - Set status to F
    - Set trigger to 0
    End workflow

Also, go ahead and update your existing workflow to look for "F" instead of "B".
Publish your workflow.  Make sure your workflow is set to run whenever an item is changed.
Create a Datasheet View, include the trigger field.  Filter so all items with status of B are listed.
Type a "1" in the trigger field and copy it down, changing the value of all items with status of B.  The workflow will kick off and change all your B values to F.
Go back and remove B selection from the status field.